# How do you print the current month, day and year using awk and date?

Tags: awk, scripting

I can't seem to grab the month, day and year using

```
awk '{print $2, $3, $6}' date
```

Does anyone know how to?

Comment: Why are you trying to use awk to grab day month and year ? Have you checked the man pages for date ?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 24):

Why use `awk` at all?

```
date +"%b %d %Y"
```

gives you the values without the hassle.

Answer (score 10):

Try piping the output from the `date` command instead, like so:

```
$ date | awk '{print $2, $3, $6}'
Dec 1 2014
```

If you truly want to take the output from `date` using a command similar to yours then you'll need to redirect it using a HERESTRING, aka. (`<<<`) (assuming a `zsh` shell or a fairly recent version of `ksh93` or `bash`).

```
$ awk '{print $2, $3, $6}' <<<$(date)
Dec 1 2014
```

This second form will take the output from the command `$(date)` and redirect it to `awk` via STDIN.

But using `awk` here is not needed at all. The `date` command has its own formatting abilities.

```
$ date +"%b %d %Y"
Dec 01 2014
```

Comment: Also note that GNU `awk` can do `date`'s part by itself: `awk 'BEGIN {print strftime("%d %b %Y")}'`

Answer (score 1):

You should pipe the output of `date` to `awk`:

```
$ date | awk '{print $2, $3, $6}'
1 Dec 2014
```

or get `date` to format it for you:

```
$ date +'%d %b %Y'
01 Dec 2014
```